# Start Activity from BaseAdapter type class

Tags: java, android

My app keeps crashing when i select item from list. I have tried literally everything that is available from previously asked questions regarding this issue. I know the issue is within something to do with the intent and context. I just can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. Some please help

```
package com.example.f4f;


import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecipesAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

private Context context;
private MainActivity activity;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Recipes> recipes;

public RecipesAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public RecipesAdapter (MainActivity a, LayoutInflater l, ArrayList<Recipes> data)
{
    this.activity = a;
    this.layoutInflater = l;
    this.recipes = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return this.recipes.size();
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled ()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0){
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate (R.layout.list_items, parent, false);

        View myView = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem);

        if(pos % 2 == 0){
            myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d3d3d3"));
        }
        holder = new MyViewHolder();
        holder.recipeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //holder.storyDesp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(this);

    Recipes recipe = recipes.get(pos);
    holder.recipe = recipe;
    holder.recipeName.setText(recipe.getrecipeName());
    holder.rating.setText(recipe.getRating());
    //holder.storyDesp.setText(news.getDesp());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) v.getTag();
    if (v instanceof View) {
        //String selectedrecipe = holder.recipe.getID();
        //String selectedrecipeurl = "http://www.yummly.com/recipe/external/"+selectedrecipe;
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.yummly.com/recipe/external/"+selectedrecipe);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, SelectedRecipeWebView.class);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
public static class MyViewHolder {
    public TextView recipeName, rating;
    public Recipes recipe;
}


}
```

> 09-08 01:10:05.933: D/dalvikvm(3346): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 21K, 3% free 3931K/4028K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
>   09-08 01:10:05.933: D/dalvikvm(3346): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 3% free 4147K/4252K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
>   09-08 01:10:05.937: I/dalvikvm-heap(3346): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.537MB for 2536932-byte allocation
>   09-08 01:10:05.941: D/dalvikvm(3346): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 6624K/6732K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
>   09-08 01:10:06.001: W/EGL_genymotion(3346): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: D/AndroidRuntime(3346): Shutting down VM
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: W/dalvikvm(3346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d28b20)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346): Process: com.example.f4f, PID: 3346
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.f4f/com.example.f4f.SelectedRecipeWebView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at com.example.f4f.RecipesAdapter.onClick(RecipesAdapter.java:99)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   09-08 01:10:07.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-08 01:10:09.529: D/dalvikvm(3388): Late-enabling CheckJNI
>   09-08 01:10:09.585: D/dalvikvm(3388): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 3% free 3582K/3692K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
>   09-08 01:10:09.621: D/libEGL(3388): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
>   09-08 01:10:09.621: D/(3388): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8e43568, tid 3388
>   09-08 01:10:09.629: D/libEGL(3388): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
>   09-08 01:10:09.629: D/libEGL(3388): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
>   09-08 01:10:09.653: W/EGL_genymotion(3388): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   09-08 01:10:09.653: E/OpenGLRenderer(3388): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
>   09-08 01:10:09.653: E/OpenGLRenderer(3388): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
>   09-08 01:10:09.661: E/OpenGLRenderer(3388): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
>   09-08 01:10:09.661: E/OpenGLRenderer(3388): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
>   09-08 01:10:09.661: D/OpenGLRenderer(3388): Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: can someone please help me fix this? i tried adding Context context to the: public RecipesAdapter (MainActivity a, LayoutInflater l, ArrayList<Recipes> data)
{
    this.activity = a;
    this.layoutInflater = l;
    this.recipes = data;
}

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized your context only within the RecipesAdapter(Context context). If you are not using this constructor while creating the instance of RecipesAdapter, your context has a null value when it is referenced. You need to initialize this value.

From the looks of this class, it looks like you used the other constructor. I am inferring this because your layoutInflater is set and apparently you do not have a problem with that.

EDIT: To pass an instance of the current context, you can replace the activity field in the constructor as RecipesAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater l, ArrayList data). I am saying this since this is the normal manner in which this is done (also because you do not seem to be using your MainActivity field anywhere).

Comment: how do I initialize the context value

Comment: Can you please check out my edited answer and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: I call the RecipesAdapter constructor in my MainActivity.java class so I don't think I can remove it replace it with Context context

Comment: Yes, you can. The reason you pass Context in the constructor to your custom adapter is to pass it the context of the activity that you are calling it from. See the constructors in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. This is how you originally initialize a custom adapter. You pass "this" is the constructor

Comment: i changed the constructor to public RecipesAdapter (Context context, LayoutInflater l, ArrayList<Recipes> data)
 {
  this.context = context;
  //this.activity = a;
  this.layoutInflater = l;
  this.recipes = data;
 }  the app is still crasing